# question about objects and how to store user inputed parameters

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am working on a project for school and I need help. How do I store a object with user determined parameters.

So this is going to ask me name, position, age, height and then it going to ask for points, blocks, and aces. After I input this with a scanner how do I store all the information inputed.

If the player object parameters entered are: Hinata, Middle Blocker, 16, 164. stat object parameters entered are: 17, 5, 2.

How do I save this object parameters and make this a unique Object?

**Main Class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Player[] players = new Player[1];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < players.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter player's name: ");
        String  data = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter player's position: ");
        String  data1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter player's age: ");
        String  data2 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter player's height");
        String  data3 = scanner.nextLine();

        Player a = new Player(data, data1, data2, data3);
        players[i] = a;

        System.out.println(a.toString());

        Scanner statScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stats[] stats = new Stats[1];
        System.out.println("\nPoints: ");
        int statData = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Blocks: ");
        int statData1 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Aces: ");
        int statData2 = scanner.nextInt();
    }

}
```

**Player class:**

```
private String name;
private String position;
private String age;
private String height;


public Player(String name, String position, String age, String height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.position = position;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}
public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String toString()
{
    String viewPlayer = new String("\nName: " + name + "\nPosition: "+ position +"\nage: "+ age + "\nheight: "+ height);
    return viewPlayer;
}

private ArrayList<Player> player;

public Player() {
    player = new ArrayList<Player>();
}

public void addFaculty(Player a)
{
    player.add(a);
}
```

**Stats class:**

```
private int points;
 private int blocks;
 private int aces;

 public Stats(int points, int blocks, int aces) {
     this.points = points;
     this.blocks = blocks;
     this.aces = aces;
 }
```